# Importing CSS & JS into portfolio and referencing them

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, email-template, css

I need to build email templates and have already been provided with the source code. I have encountered 2 issues:

1. When I try to reference the CSS I have uploaded in the portfolio, SFMC doesnt seem to reference it.

   ```
   < link rel= stylesheet  href = "/*ET Link to CSS *?">
   ```
2. When I try to upload JavaScript files, I receive an error message saying that file type is not recognized, even thought the documentation clearly states .js files can be loaded to porfolio : http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/portfolio/

Comment: For CSS, make sure your formatting is correct (no spaces), and that your link to the portfolio is https over http. Example: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://[ImageLink&Name].css"/>

For JavaScript I encountered the same problem a while ago and resorted to referencing files hosted outside of SFMC - would be interested to hear if anybody has a workaround.

Comment: @AnonWonderer thanks for your comment. Can you explain what you mean by "no spaces" in the CSS?

Comment: I wasn't sure if it just was the formatting of your post or not, but you have for example < link rel= stylesheet, when it should be <link rel="stylesheet"  -- so just making sure there aren't spaces after the equals sign and making sure quotation marks are directly surrounding the words.

Comment: Are you trying to reference external files from email?  This wont work - css needs to be inline for an email, and client side scripting (js) wont work in email either.

Comment: @DavidJackman Thanks for the heads up. Used it inline and its working now.  Would love to know why marketing cloud let's you upload CSS, but not use it in emails??

Comment: Its actually not specific to marketing cloud, but email in general - no email client out there will allow for the referencing of external files or client side scripts as a security feature.  Uploading css files would be used for landing pages or cloud pages.

Comment: 2) If you zip the file and then upload it will allow you to upload JS files into portfolio